# Expect script is not working on linux machine

Tags: linux, scripting, expect

when I have to do ssh to one of my machine below is the command and if I type 'yes' it is working and able to login  as below.

```
ssh root@192.168.1.177
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.177 (192.168.1.177)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:KqI6oKKY1JOH+OJZzCYObPdkMVNNwhkaMGTYgx/fDxE.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.177' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
localhost ~ #
```

Same thing I am trying through expect script and it throws me error as below.

```
 ./expectscriptssh.sh 192.168.1.177
spawn ssh root@192.168.1.177
invalid command name "fingerprint"
    while executing
"fingerprint"
    invoked from within
"expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? ""
    (file "./expectscriptssh.sh" line 4).
```

Below is my expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set VAR [lindex $argv 1]
spawn ssh root@$argv 
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? "
send "yes\r"
```

Can any body suggest, how can I resolve this.

Comment: Aren't `expect` patterns regular expressions? In that case, `)?` is not matching a question mark after a right parentheses, but says "match an optional `)`". Likewise `[fingeprint]` would match one of the characters in `[...]`. Even if they are only globbing patterns, `[fingerprint]` would cause an issue for you.

Comment: @Kusalananda Whilst patterns in expect can be regular expressions, they are not by default. One uses `-re` as a switch to enable them.

Comment: @icarus Ah, there you go. Your TCL-foo is stronger than mine.

Comment: Thanks much.  I tried your inputs and now script is working for me. Really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TCL, the [ ] pair is a call to do command substitution, rather like $( ) is in POSIX shells.

If you have `autoexpect` available then the simplest way to write an expect script is to use autoexpect to watch you doing something and then edit the resulting script to remove unneeded stuff.

You can change the "..." to {...} to avoid the evaluation of the string.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set VAR [lindex $argv 1]
spawn ssh root@$argv 
expect {Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? }
send "yes\r"
```

Usually you want something more, to allow the prompt to be optional, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set VAR [lindex $argv 1]
spawn ssh root@$argv 
expect {
    {Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? } {
        exp_send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    {Password:} {send "secret\r"}
    {# }
}
```

Comment: @ Kusalananda &  @glenn jackman:  I would like to thank both of you for all the inputs and help.   I took your inputs and tried again. Script looks good and working for me. Thanks a lot. Below is how script looks now and it is perfectly working.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/expect                                                                                                                                                set VAR [lindex $argv 1]
set timeout 60
log_file -noappend myfile.log
spawn -noecho ssh root@$argv
expect {
  timeout {send "exit\r"}
  "*connecting (yes/no/*)?" { send -- "yes\r"}
   "localhost*" { send -- "exit\r"}
    }
expect {
        "localhost*"  
        { send   "exit\r"} 
  
}

Comment: Thank you glenn jackman. I tried inputs. Script is working for me. Thanks bunch.

Comment: @Rags Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @icarus, I am not sure how you got that to work.  From the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981382/how-to-escape-square-brackets-in-expect), we still need the escape character for the square brackets.  Thus, `[fingerprint]` should change to `\[fingerprint\]` for it to work.

Comment: @CaTx The point is that in TCL `{}`  (braces) quotes things, rather like single quotes do in the shell. In the question you reference they are using double quotes in the script, which would need the `[]` (brackets) to be escaped with backslash.